# SQL Monitor report for multiple queries

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, rdbms

I need to generate report_sql_monitor for set of queries sequentially with spooling into file.
So I have the following:

1. File where the queries are (e.g. test.sql)
2. Spool file (e.g. output.txt)

> Test.sql / **Below is the corrected version**:

```
   set pagesize 1000
   set echo off
   set feedback on
   set timing on
   set autotrace on stat
   define file=./output.txt
   define file
   col prev_sql_id new_value SQLID --get the SQL_ID of previous query to put it further into report_sql_monitor
   select /*+ Monitor */ name, last_name from family --first query 
   /
   select prev_id from v$session where sid = sys_context('USERENV','SID') --get SQL_ID
    /
    spool &file
    select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(
    sql_id => '&SQLID',
    type = > 'TEXT',
    report_level => 'ALL') as report from dual --Report was generated
    /
    spool off --close spooling 
    --the second query
    select /*+ Monitor */ salary,month from salary
    /
    select prev_sql_id from v$session where sid =sys_context('USERENV','SID') --get SQL_ID
    /
    spool &file append
    select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(
    sql_id => '&SQLID',
    type = > 'TEXT',
    report_level => 'ALL') as report from dual -- REPORT IS NOT GENERATED
    /
    spool off
```

> The problem is that the above test.sql generates report_sql_monitor report only for the first query with 'statistics'. The resulting file (output.txt) is expected to have the following:

1. SQL Monitoring Report **for each query** in test.sql - **NOT DONE**
2. After SQL Monitoring Reports there should be standard query statistics data - ***IS DONE***:

Statistics

```
xx recursive call

xx db block gets

xx consistent gets

xx physical reads

and so forth
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: @OldProgrammer report_sql_monitor is not generated for the second query, only for the first. However I need to have it generated for *each sequential* query in test.sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-79E97A84-9C27-4A5E-AC0D-C12CB3E748E6.htm):

> SQL monitoring is automatically started when a SQL statement runs
>   parallel or when it has consumed at least 5 seconds of CPU or I/O
>   time.

Add the [`MONITOR`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements006.htm#BABDCEIG) hint to force the statment to be monitored:

```
select /*+ monitor */ salary,month from salary
/
```

Monitoring data may also be missing for the following reasons, although I doubt they apply here:

1. Data ages out, usually within tens of minutes.
2. Bugs that prevent large, weird statements from being monitored.
3. Hidden parameters that control monitoring behavior.

Comment: Hi Jon, Great it works. So I updated my script and everyone can use it for their goal.